# It it posssible to skip found files within found folders when using find?

Tags: find, macos

I am looking for a command that only outputs the following two folders and skips found files within found folders.

```
/Users/sunknudsen/Library/Application Scripts/com.brothersroloff.SyncBuddy
/Users/sunknudsen/Library/Containers/com.brothersroloff.SyncBuddy
```

```
$ find ~/Library -iname "*syncbuddy*" 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"
/Users/sunknudsen/Library/Application Scripts/com.brothersroloff.SyncBuddy
/Users/sunknudsen/Library/Containers/com.brothersroloff.SyncBuddy
/Users/sunknudsen/Library/Containers/com.brothersroloff.SyncBuddy/Data/Library/Application Support/com.brothersroloff.SyncBuddy
/Users/sunknudsen/Library/Containers/com.brothersroloff.SyncBuddy/Data/Library/Application Support/com.brothersroloff.SyncBuddy/SyncBuddy.storedata
/Users/sunknudsen/Library/Containers/com.brothersroloff.SyncBuddy/Data/Library/Preferences/com.brothersroloff.SyncBuddy.plist
/Users/sunknudsen/Library/Containers/com.brothersroloff.SyncBuddy/Data/Library/Application Scripts/com.brothersroloff.SyncBuddy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the top-most matches, you can prune matching directories after printing them:

```
find ~/Library -iname "*syncbuddy*" -print -prune
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks Stephen!